# Add a button to open an URL (Preferences Bundle)

Tags: bundle, preferences, theos, tweak

I'm trying to add a button in my Preferences Bundle to open an URL in Safari (or in the Pref Bundle).

I'm looking this: https://github.com/hbang/NotiQuiet/blob/master/prefs/ADNQListController.m
But I don't understand the else, if eccc...

I want just a button (for example "My website") that open www.mywebsite.com

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following dictionary to your preferences plist:

`{
    action = link;
    cell = PSButtonCell;
    label = "Google";
}`

And the following method to your bundle:

`- (void)link {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com"]];
}`